# I can't get my subrouter to work properly

Tags: http, go, server, routes

I have a router like so

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/static/styles/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/styles/",
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/styles"))))

    book := r.PathPrefix("/books").Subrouter()
    book.HandleFunc("/issued-books/", IssuedBooks)
    book.HandleFunc("/top-trending/", ShowTopTrending)
    book.HandleFunc("/", ShowAllBooks)
    book.HandleFunc("/available/", ShowAvailable)

    r.HandleFunc("/", ShowHome)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
```

The basic handler function structure is below:

```
func ShowAvailable(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        tmp := Store{}

        for ix, val := range JSON.Books {
               status := &val.IssueStatus
               if *status == false {
                     tmp.Books = append(tmp.Books, JSON.Books[ix])
                }
         }
         renderTemplate(&w, "available.html", &tmp)
    }
```

renderTemplate is defined like so :

```
func renderTempate(w *http.ResponseWriter, filename string, tmp *Store) {

    path := "static/" + filename
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(path))

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    if err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, filename, *tmp); err != nil {
           http.Error(*w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
           return
    }
     mime.AddExtensionType(".css", "text/css; charset=utf-8")
    res := *w
    res.Write(buf.Bytes())
    res.(http.Flusher).Flush()
}
```

The first Issue is it never renders the css file correctly....the browser always ends up saying ....
Refused to apply style sheet from /path/to/css.... because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type....and i tried using the MIME package to set it correctly just before sending the processed template to the client but it still wont work.

The Second Issue is the HTML rendering becomes inconsistent....only the ShowAllBooks page displayed, others didn't,
giving a 404 error...for this i tried removing the forward slash from the URL paths and it all pages displayed...so the forward slash affects the page rendering...any help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove ending slashed for routes:

```golang
    book.HandleFunc("/issued-books", IssuedBooks)
    book.HandleFunc("/top-trending", ShowTopTrending)
    book.HandleFunc("/", ShowAllBooks)
    book.HandleFunc("/available", ShowAvailable)
```

css is supported by GO out of the box - https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/mime/type.go#L60

Check what exactly server returns for for css links. Could it be 404?

Comment: The pages render only HTML after removing it...but the point is that is what i want.
Also...even after removing it the browser still gives the MIME type error...after removing the css still isn't applied

Comment: please add server response (all headers) for CSS request to your question

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/